# Making my computer talk (with the say command)

Tags: command-line, text-to-speech

I've been using the `say` command in terminal to get my computer to talk, ie.

```
say "Hello"
```

How can I pipe the text of a .txt file to the `say` command to get it to read aloud the text in a file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `say` has this option (see `man say`)

```
say -f stuff.txt
```

Or you can use command substitution...

```
say $(cat stuff.txt)
```

this passes the output of `cat stuff.txt` as an argument to `say` (the quotes " " are not needed)

Comment: That's too awesome. I should have figured that out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am just adding that if you really want to *pipe* the output of a command to the `say` command, you can use [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

Basically, just doing

```
mkfifo myNamedPipe
say -f myNamedPipe &
cat > myNamedPipe
```

should allow you to use speech synthesis on an arbitrary source (here, words from the keyboard using cat).

*I do not however have the required configuration to actually try this, so I could have got something wrong.*